# Why is pg_restore that slow and PostgreSQL almost not even using the CPU?

Tags: postgresql, performance, cpu-usage, postgresql-13

I just had to use `pg_restore` with a small dump of 30MB and it took in average 5 minutes! On my colleagues' computers, it is ultra fast, like a dozen of seconds. The difference between the two is the CPU usage: while for the others, the database uses quite a bunch of CPU (60-70%) during the restore operation, on my machine, it stays around a few percents only (0-3%) as if it was not active at all.

The exact command was : `pg_restore -h 127.0.0.1 --username XXX --dbname test --no-comments test_dump.sql`

The originating command to produce this dump was: `pg_dump --dbname=XXX --user=XXX --no-owner --no-privileges --verbose --format=custom --file=/sql/test_dump.sql`

Look at the screenshot taken in the middle of the restore operation:

[image: Screenshot during the restore]

Here is the corresponding `vmstat 1` result running the command:

[image: Screenshot of vmstat]

I've looked at the web for a solution during a few hours but this under-usage of the CPU remains quite mysterious. Any idea will be appreciated.

For the stack, I am on Ubuntu 20.04 and postgres version 13.6 is running into a docker container. I have a decent hardware, neither bad nor great.

EDIT: This very same command worked in the past on my machine with a same common HDD but now it is terribly slow. The only difference I saw with others (for whom it is blazing fast) was really on the CPU-usage from my point of view (even if they have an SSD which shouldn't be at all the limiting factor especially with a 30 MB dump).

EDIT 2: For those who proposed the problem was about IO-boundness and maybe a slow disk, I just tried without any conviction to run my command on an SSD partition I just made and nothing has changed.

Comment: A dump isn't a backup, it's a batch file full of INSERT statements. Executing 30MB worth of INSERT statements will be affected by IO throughput and delays. Since you use a container, IO will be slow because the actual database files are inside the container. Increasing the size of the database will require increasing the size of the container image. This will be *at least* twice as slow as using a physical database file

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks, I didn't get your point, look at the EDIT maybe but for me, it is related to computation running too slow and the CPU not being used enough compared to others

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos. 1) By default a Postgres is not compromised of `INSERT`s it uses `COPY` to import data. You can force it to use `INSERT`s with `--inserts`  or `--column-inserts`, but that is not what eytienne did. 2) Depending on how you specify the command a dump can include more then just data. 3) A dump can be point in time backup of an entire database or using `pg_dumpall` an entire cluster.

Comment: That's still not a backup, it's a script. It may be called a "logical" backup but it's actually a script. That's slow and will cause the database file to increase, thus causing the image to increase.  An actual, physical backup taken with `pg_basebackup` would be a lot faster to take *and* restore

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos. Huh? You have empty database you restore the `pg_dump` file to it and you end up with the same thing in `$PGDATA` as you would with `pg_basebackup`. I have no idea what you are talking about database file increasing.

Answer (score 5):

The `vmstat` output shows that you are I/O bound. Get faster storage, and performance will improve.

Comment: Thank you, I am not really convinced so I put an EDIT to explain it.

Comment: @eytienne but your edit doesn't make any sense.  The same script did something different when applied to something different?  So what.

Comment: What then is your interpretation of the high iowait% value? Perhaps the disk is kept busy by something else.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Maybe you should drop your answer regarding my second EDIT... (if you have some other idea?)

Comment: What does `vmstat 1` show on your fast disk?

Comment: I finally changed my machine and it is OK now but the other answer with tuning may help.

Comment: The other answer is dangerous, bad advice.

Answer (score 2):

[PostgreSQL, by default, is tuned for data durability. Usually transactions are flushed to the disk at each and every commit, forcing write-through of any disk write cache,](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/runtime-config-wal.html#:%7E:text=The%20default%20is%20to%20enable%20fsync%2C%20for%20maximum%20reliability.) so it seems to be very IO-bound.

When restoring database from a dump file, it may make sense to lower these durability settings, especially if the restore is done while your application is offline, especially in non-production environments.

I temporarily run `postgres` with these options: `-c fsync=off -c synchronous_commit=off -c full_page_writes=off -c checkpoint_flush_after=256 -c autovacuum=off -c max_wal_senders=0`

Refer to these documentation sections for more information:

- [14.4.9. Some Notes about pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/populate.html#POPULATE-PG-DUMP)
- [14.5. Non-Durable Settings.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/non-durability.html)

Also this article:

- [Settings for a fast pg_restore](http://www.databasesoup.com/2014/09/settings-for-fast-pgrestore.html)

Comment: I would warn everybody *not* to follow this advice. Setting `fsync = off` is not only a sacrifice in durability, but it will break your database and cause data corruption if you have a crash. The same holds for `full_page_writes = off`. You can only change these two parameters if you are ready to restore from backup.The other parameters are safe, but `max_wal_senders` will offer no benefit, as far as I know.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe " You can only change these two parameters if you are ready to restore from backup."  Well, yeah... that's why you're doing pg_restore in the first place (especially if you have the luxury of restarting the instance).